# Missing Eth using uniswap

Tags: ether, uniswap

I tried purchasing crypto through uniswap and the transaction was taking a long time. I decided to cancel it forgetting you lose the gas fee. Turns out I lost the gas fee and all the eth used to purchase the coins. I should be refunded those but was not. My wallet address is 0x60b49d5229685422191cFAF73670A64FB8441dBF

Please let me know what happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You swapped 0.11 ETH for KAWA 5hr ago : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x497e7b1a5f9195c8acc19e76cd878c512b4d2f8d6078b997e36a12a1e569f46e

You might need to add custom token to your wallet (here KAWA : 0x546aed37d202d607f45cbd2b8c0cad0d25fbe339 , cf previous link) - for metamask: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-add-unlisted-tokens-custom-tokens-in-MetaMask

Answer (score 0):

Unhappily for you everything went right:

First you transferred `0.20666637 ETH` from Hotbit Exchange to your ETH wallet and payed `0.0046242273 ETH` transaction fee:

[image]

Then you swapped `0.11 ETH` and therefore payed `0.057532143311567874 ETH` transaction fee:

[image]

So after this swap your account remains with `0.039134226688432126 ETH` and the `26,698,462.490302160419541048 KAWA` you got from the swap:

[image]